# Is it allowed to bind descriptor sets that are allocated from different descriptor pools?

Tags: vulkan

Is it allowed to bind descriptor sets that are allocated from different descriptor pools? If so, is there any performance issue with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descriptor pools are nothing more than allocators for descriptors. Outside of allocation/deallocation, they have no effect on the descriptors that they create.